Perl module ExtUtils::Embed requires itself to be compiled
I have an incomplete Perl 5.16.3 install on a CentOS server for which I don't have administrative rights. I am trying to install ExtUtils::Embed which normally should be part of the Perl install.
So this is the same problem as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150139/4614641
except that the command cpanm D/DO/DOUGM/ExtUtils-Embed-1.14.tar.gz fails at some point by stating :
Can't locate ExtUtils/Embed.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...)

(I am using local::lib environment variables).
So I tried the following manual install:
$ curl -LO https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DO/DOUGM/ExtUtils-Embed-1.14.tar.gz
$ tar xzf ExtUtils-Embed-1.14.tar.gz && cd ExtUtils-Embed-1.14/

and
$ perl Makefile.PL

which does not strictly fails but says:
Writing files for ExtUtils::Embed tests...
Can't locate ExtUtils/Embed.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ./lib [...] .) at ../genmake line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../genmake line 5.
Can't locate ExtUtils/Embed.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ./lib [...] .) at ../genmake line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../genmake line 5.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: NAME must be a package name
Warning: LINKTYPE set to '', no longer necessary
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils-Embed
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

Then:
$ make  # OK

cp lib/ExtUtils/Embed.pm blib/lib/ExtUtils/Embed.pm
cp lib/Embed/Persistent.pm blib/lib/Embed/Persistent.pm
Manifying 1 pod document

but make test fails, and this is what fails when using cpanm as well:
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/build.t ......... make[1]: Makefile.embed : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
make[1]: *** Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « Makefile.embed ». Arrêt.
t/build.t ......... 1/2 make[1]: Makefile.loop : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
make[1]: *** Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « Makefile.loop ». Arrêt.
t/build.t ......... Failed 2/2 subtests 
t/embed.t ......... No subtests run 
t/loop.t .......... sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
sh: ./loop: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
t/loop.t .......... Failed 18/18 subtests 
t/multiplicity.t .. skipped: (no reason given)

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/build.t       (Wstat: 0 Tests: 2 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  1-2
t/embed.t       (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/loop.t        (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 18 tests but ran 0.
Files=4, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.01 sys +  0.03 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 3/4 test programs. 2/2 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Erreur 255

After closer inspection, Makefile.PL executes genmake, which is the one importing ExtUtils::Embed.
Is it critical? Can I ignore this failure and run make install? Otherwise how to install this missing package?
EDIT
I found how to make genmake run using the Extlib::Embed from the current directory.
In fact, the genmake file had a line use lib qw(./lib); which works if you run it from the root folder... However, the system call made by Makefile.PL is run from the subdirectory ./t/ so it does not work.
So this line in Makefile.PL:
    system "$^X ../genmake $_ Makefile.$_ $libperl{$_}";

has to be changed to:
    system "PERL5LIB=../lib $^X ../genmake $_ Makefile.$_ $libperl{$_}";

Now running perl Makefile.PL succeeds (but the make test fails for another reason which I suspect is the lack of the correct perl-devel files...).

Perl 5.16.3 comes with ExtUtils::Embed version 1.30, not 1.14.

@choroba, yes, but since it is now part of the full Perl installation, this means I have to download and compile the whole of Perl... which I will do anyway for simplicity, given the unusable state of the current system-wide installation.

@choroba, Looks like E::E stopped being dual-lifed after 1.14, being only available as part of the Perl distro afterwards.

@PlasmaBinturong Even if the correct version isn't available standalone, you can't just use the wrong version! Install your own Perl (perhaps using perlbrew).

@PlasmaBinturong - yes, grab your own copy of 5.16.3 and get yourself going. Then since you are grabbing your own copy anyway, download 5.40 (latest version, released this sprint) and try to use that. My suspicion is that you will need to make few changes to get your app to run on the latest version.
